# Is convolution in CNNs a similarity measure

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

Is it correct to say that convolution in CNNs is a similarity measure between filter and receptive field? and what is the difference between correlation and convolution?

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree. Similarity measures quantify the similarity between two objects. For example the Euclidian distance calculates the similarity of vectors.

Convolutional layers, so filters, on the other hand extract features out of complex objects. By convolving an image with for example a sobel filter you can detect edges and so create a feature map.

The deeper a filter is in the network the more complex are the features you are getting.